# What is the destination of unenlightened monk reviling Noble Layperson?

Tags: karma, mara, evil, vipaka

I recall reading the Buddhist scriptures say those who revile Noble Ones are reborn in hell.

Does this also apply to an unenlightened (puthujjana) monk that reviles a Noble Layperson?

Comment: not disagreeing, but I wondered if you could quote the sutta that appears in? obviously, many mahayanists are somewhat offensive to Buddhist saints.

Answer (score 0):

Sure. But they wouldn't risk much here in regard of touch Noble Ones, or? Even a fault couldn't be expected here, as not possible to trace it an area of Upasaka, Upasika, for the most.

How ever, even if a Noble One would act wrongly toward another, such would block his progress as long as not pardoned, brought to be solved again.

*[Note that this isn't given for stacks, exchange, other world-binding trades, but for an escape frim this wheel]*